# phonegap app no network connection on Android 9 Pie but working on Android 8 (Oreo)

Tags: android, html, phonegap

I have a phone gap app that is working on every Android Version except 9 Pie.
app is login with login credential  in Android 8 but not working on android 9

```
       <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
      xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"id="com.mitraye.earthinfosys" 
         version="6.5.0">
         <name>Earth Infosys</name>
         <description></description>
         <description></description>
         <author href="http://mitraye.com" 
         email="support@mitraye.com">Mitraye</author>
         <content src="index.html"/>
         <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
         <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />   
         <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
         <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
         <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
         <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
         <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
         <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
         <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
         <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
         <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
         <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
         <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
         <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>

         <preference name="windows-arch" value="anycpu" />

        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="20" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
        <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="28" />
        <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>

        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1"/>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" 
      spec="~1.0.2"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-native-spinner" source="npm" spec="~1.1.3"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" 
      spec="~1.2.0"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0"/>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1"/>
      <access origin="*"/>
      <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
      <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
      <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
      <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
      <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
      <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
      <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
      </platform>
      <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
      </platform>
      <icon src="icon.png"/>
      <splash src="splash.png" />
      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.myapp"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
      </manifest>
      <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
      <splash platform="android" qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/android/screen- 
       ldpi-portrait.png" />
      <splash platform="android" qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/android/screen- 
      mdpi-portrait.png" />
      <splash platform="android" qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/android/screen- 
      hdpi-portrait.png" />
      <splash platform="android" qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/android/screen- 
      xhdpi-portrait.png" />


       </widget>
```

need minSdkVersion of 17 for apps to work with android 9. Mine has 19 already. TargetSdkVersion is 28.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Were you able to solve it in any way?

Comment: you can use https for android 9 it is not working for http

Comment: I got it working by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Although, I later had to move my server to `https://`.

Comment: I can confirm that it is not working with http, but does work with https, any more info why this is happening would be very appreciated